# Location of action.yaml (or action.yml) files

Tags: github-actions

In the course I'm doing on Pluralsight covering workflows, we're not really covering action.yaml(yml) files in full.

From this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions):

> "All actions require a metadata file. The metadata filename must be either action.yml or action.yaml. The data in the metadata file defines the inputs, outputs, and runs configuration for your action."

The yaml we type in/ follow along with,  works on my workflows.  But ... WHERE are the REQUIRED `action.yml` files?  I'm not writing them, they're not copied and pasted, etc. Yet the workflows do run.

From the course I copied these URLs and browsed to them:

[Git Hub Actions](https://github.com/actions/github-script/blob/main/action.yml)

[webapps-deploy Actions](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/blob/master/action.yml)

Do these yaml files get used from any workflow whether directly referenced or not?  Maybe this is the case and I'm missing it.

Google searches for 'action.yaml file location' doesn't yield any answers.

If they must exist (required) then they should exist.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The question is unclear. Each action used references (directly or indirectly) a git-repository, branch and path. Take, for example, [`https://github.com/turing85/publish-report`](https://github.com/turing85/publish-report) which has an `action.yml`, that is used here: [`https://github.com/turing85/advent-of-code-2022/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml#L39`](https://github.com/turing85/advent-of-code-2022/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml#L39). In the same workflow file, we see that we can also self-reference repositories on, e.g. .ine 100.

Comment: Turing, I sometimes over-include detail thinking it is necessary.  Failure to communicate on my part is clear.

The 2 links above appear in the course I'm doing.  Instructor is on vacation and I'm doing one of his recorded courses.

From what I'm seeing, action.yml is required.  My workflows, created while following along, run without them.  At least I can't find any action.yml files in mine.

Are these inherited under the hood?  From a workflow, how can one find its action.yml file? Appears silly, yes.  Has to be there, can't find it.

Clear as mud? :)

Comment: Actions != workflows. Each `uses` in a workflow includes an action. As I said: each action used references (directly or indirectly) a git-repository, branch and path. Those point to a directory holding an `action.yml`. I recommend going over the links I linked above. I think they should clarify things.

Comment: Thanks, was in the process of using your advice from earlier as well.

Located my misunderstanding.  Was confused about what the instructor was referring to.

See the screen shots.

Comment: This is a conundrum. As someone who browses for the `github-actions` tag to find things to answer, I would have considered this within the scope of the tag; "actions" have no meaning outside the context of workflows, and looking at it now it is a bit odd that the `github-actions` tag doesn't specifically include "actions" -- there aren't any [`github-workflows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-workflows) tagged. Should the tag be updated to reflect that it encompasses the "Actions" as well???

Answer (score 2):

Actions and Workflows are distinct. They both include the concept of `steps:` that can be either `runs:` and `uses:` -- where a `runs:` is a step you define, and `uses:` is an *invocation of an action*.

"Actions" ([syntax here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions)) are reusable *sets of **steps*** that you can `uses` as part of a job. They don't run on their own. An example that appears a lot will be `actions/checkout`. You summon actions in the form of `uses: <user-name>/<repo-name>[/<optional-internal-dir>]@<ref>`, and this is summoning the `action.y[a]ml` that exists at `<user-name>/<repo-name>[/<optional-internal-dir>]`, i.e. `uses: actions/checkout@v3` is invoking [this files](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3/action.yml), which is aware of it's adjacent files and can use them per the docs on how to write actions. An example of a repo with many actions, for example, if you build anything in R, could be [r-lib/actions](https://github.com/r-lib/actions). To give a more precise example, the R setup action lives in a subfolder, and would be called according to that subfolder name, like [`uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2`](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/v2/setup-r/action.yml)

"Workflows" ([syntax here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions)) are the pipelines in each repo under the folder `./.github/workflows` that **actually run** per their *triggering events*, like on push ([full list here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows)). They can be composed of jobs that `runs:` something or `uses:` an action. An important difference though, is that workflows with a triggering event `on:` of `workflow_call:` can be invoked with a `uses:` at the "job" level of a workflow. Workflows consist of multiple jobs which can either `uses:` a `workflow_call` triggered workflow file, or outline their own `steps:`, and only the `uses:` under `steps:` is invoking an *Action*.

Comment: This is quite helpful but my confusion was on a path tangent to this :)

Finally got it -- a bit more coffee for me over here in the States ... should wake me up and I'll be just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Student was confused :)  Hate it when I do that.

As Turing pointed out (and his SO name is apt): Actions != workflows. Each uses in a workflow includes an action. As I said: each action used references (directly or indirectly) a git-repository, branch and path.

Looking at the instructors sentence over and over, with this input, saw where I was combining ideas:

What the instructor actually meant:

[image]

What I thought the instructor meant:

[image]

I had thought the repo I was using meant my repo.  So naturally when I could not find the action.yml files in MY REPOSITORY WHICH WAS UNDERSTOOD TO BE THE ONE BEING USED :) it got a bit frustrating.

The REPO BEING USED (humorously using caps here) is overloaded.  Of course I'm 'using' my repo but in this case it is meant 'the repo where the inherited (if this is correct term) action.yml lives.'

I had the choice of deleting the post and hiding my confusion or owning it.  I chose the latter.

Turing, thank you for leading me in the right path.  Kim, sorry for the overt honesty -- as you can see the confusion was mine and I learned from it.

In the future, no matter how many confusions learners such as myself have tossed at you, teach FIRST. :) 'Never attribute to malice that which is best explained by stupidity' (author unknown)

Comment: "Each uses in a workflow includes an action" has an exception, and the distinction betwen `uses` in a `job` vs `uses` in a job's `steps` is not trivial, and important to understand before deciding which one you want to create per your use case.

Comment: Thanks VERY much.  This is really very helpful.

I am just learning this and have been over these clips of the current module for the third time.  There is much detail here in these clips and the way to make it all 2nd nature is repetition.

Instructor points out the action for JavaScript, Docker, Composite and as well points out this course doesn't fully cover all 3 of these.

Perhaps this is what you mean by these distinctions not being trivial.

If you know of courses / videos that delve more into this, please include.

Comment: Turing, not sure of what I did wrong here.  Did upvote where any helpful input (including David's ) happened.  I don't think I misused this except with Kim, which David already handled.

Clarify please -- is there more to learn here?

Thanks for your input.